# Send a mail with exchange server without using SMTP in scala or java

Tags: scala, jakarta-mail

In my app, we are using MS exchange server for sending emails. But we are not using SMTP . We have to send mails without using SMTP.

Earlier i send the mail with Gail server with SMTP. but I didn't find any solution for sending mail with exchange server without the use of SMTP.

Please suggest me a good solution for this

**EDIT** :
Php code

```
<?php

// Set basic message parameters
$from = 'noreply@company.com';
$to = 'customer@example.com';
$subject = 'Test Message';
$message = 'Hello';

// Set additional headers for HTML email
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from;

// Send mail
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      echo 'Message sent';
} else {
      echo 'Message sending failed';
}

?>
```

Is it possible to send mail without use of SMTP port and host ?

Comment: I have updated a php code for sending mail which we were using earlier. I dont know PHP much so not getting properly .

Comment: Where does come from the `mail()` method from your PHP code ? Could you show it ?

Comment: the mail() function is native to PHP. The manual page can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

**Basically you cannot send e-mails without interacting an SMTP server (may it happen implicitly).**

The `mail()` function of PHP actually executes a native binary (e.g., the `sendmail` command on a Linux/Unix environment, but on Windows it needs some configuration to work properly -- which OS do you have there?).

So if you want to use the same mechanism, call the binary `sendmail` command (`ProcessBuilder`, `Runtime.exec()` are your friends in Java, or the [scala.sys.process.package](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) in Scala).

Comment: Then just call the `sendmail` command (I suppose it is configured properly -- try sending a mail by hand on your Linux box).

Comment: How to call this method and what parameters I have to pass in it ? can you briefly tell me ?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail) for one possible approach. As I mentioned, you can use Runtime.exec(), the process Scala package, and additional 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails using Exchange Web Services if they are accessible on your server.

[Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) you can download EWS Java API. It's quite old (and poorly coded), but should be enough to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

Try [exJello](http://www.exjello.org/)  or [Moonrug Exchange Connector](http://www.moonrug.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that I find myself using quite frequently within Spark Pipelines that uses the sendmail function (built into almost all linux distributions) and sends the emails as HTML(s). I mainly use it in situations where the admins already have postfix configured (almost all).

It uses base64 encoding to encode an html template in scala then seamlessly decodes and executes in bash without any of the monstrous headaches that come with combining bash string interpolation with scala and process execution. No temp files, just pure execution.

> NOTES: 
>   1) if you use it like me in spark cluster mode you should test it on all of your data nodes first because it will execute from one of them and fail. 
>   2) I don't catch stdout because I don't need it. If you do just add a Stringbuffer and split the output with a logger at the end of message_success val.

#### Send Html email

```scala
import java.util.Base64
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import scala.sys.process._

def scalaSendMail(html_message: String, subject: String, to: Array[String], from: String=""): String = {
    val message64 = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(html_message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    val prepped_recipients = to.mkString(",")
    val bash_wrapper = """(echo "From: """ + from + """";
       echo "To: """ + prepped_recipients + """";
       echo "Subject: """ + subject + """";
       echo "Content-Type: text/html";
       echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
       echo "";
       echo """" + message64 + """" | base64 --decode
    ) | sendmail -t """ 
    val mesage_success = Seq("sh", "-c", bash_wrapper).!!
    return mesage_success
}
```